# little 'browsergame' with nodejs (express) and mysql

Tags: node.js, rest, express

as a little project I want to create a browsergame. It's very simple:
Landingpage, where user can login and then go into the game.
The Game itself looks similiar to everyone, just with different values, ie user A has 10.000 iron and 7.500 copper, where user B has 12.000 iron and 5.000 copper.
Thats all, I'm not planning on making this a complete game, I just want to know how it works. Also, I don't need help with the database server-side logic for the game, but the communication between frontend and backend is not clear to me.

What I think it should look like:

User:
Frontend -> Landingpage; user logs in

Server:
Backend -> receives requests, like users logging in, checking ressources etc
        -> sends results back to the user (frontend), where the content of the page is filled with the information from the server

Database:
database stuff, not important

In my mind, the user types in a certain adress ie game.mydomain.com and lands on the index.html
How can I then send requests to the nodejs server and receive the results?

I hope this is not too fuzzy...

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have plenty of ways how you can execute request in JavaScript.

Assuming that you have your node.js server deployed on some server (some.server.com) and your routes are configured to handle request like `/login`, `/resources`, etc. All you need to do is... execute request from your index.html in using JavaScript.

You have plenty of ways how to do that:

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/here-is-the-most-popular-ways-to-make-an-http-request-in-javascript-954ce8c95aaa

For example using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API):

```
fetch('some.server.com/resources').then(responseFromServer => console.log(responseFromServer ))
```

Comment: thank you very much! I'm going to take a deeper look on these methods!